# Allow for variable to be used in local scope

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, legacy-code

I'm looking at a large legacy project where variables declared in `for` statements are used outside the scope. VS2013 doesn't like that and give compiler errors.

How can I tell VStudio to allow that?

```
for (CBookmarks::iterator it = m_listBookmarks.begin();
    !(it==m_listBookmarks.end()) && hSelected!=it->hParent;
    it++);

CString Hierarchy = LookupHierarchy(it->hParent);
```

***It's a large project which I do not maintain. I'm just reading the source code and trying to run it as a reference for a new project. I do not want to "fix" the code base.***

**Edit**

For some reason I still get compile errors despite configuring:

[image]

I tried changing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 but I still get compilation errors.

Comment: `it++);` remove the extra semi-colon

Comment: @Borgleader: That would lead to unwanted behavior. It's legacy code which works fine. I just want to tell vstudio to allow usage of the variable outside the for scope. (i do not maintain the application, just reading/running it as reference for a new project)

Comment: I know you said you can't/don't want to change the code, but why not use a single regular expression to fix all the `for` loops in the entire codebase, then recompile. Shouldn't take as long as waiting for a different answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
/Zc:forScope-
```

As documented: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx

But I really hate the idea of using such a switch. I would suggest just using the following change which will have the same effect:

```
CBookmarks::iterator it = m_listBookmarks.begin();
for (;
    !(it==m_listBookmarks.end()) && hSelected!=it->hParent;
    it++);

CString Hierarchy = LookupHierarchy(it->hParent);
```

**Important** You need to remove the pre compiled header cachefile (*.pch) after you activate the setting, as it has no effect otherwise.

Comment: the same behavior is used in a lot of places. They are using an old version of VStudio which do not give any compile errors. I can't change all.

Comment: Took the liberty to update your answer a bit with the piece that I missed.

Comment: @tenfour -"But I really hate the idea of using such a switch." - "if you can not, but really want, then you can" - it is (hidden) idea of C++. Wrongly applied - it is UB.

Comment: What is UB? In standard C++ it's an error, not UB. With `/Zc:forScope-` it's neither an error or UB.

Comment: The irony of "if you can not, but really want,..." - is UB wrongly applied. Forget it...